# Non-intuitive results from glm

Tags: generalized-linear-model, p-value, interpretation

I conducted a reciprocal transplant experiment to look for local adaptation of aphids populations on their host tree populations.  I have 3 populations of both aphids and trees (and each aphid population was placed on each of the tree populations). I also created a variable called "homeaway" in which I categorized each aphid-tree combination as either "home" (when aphids were transplanted on their native tree population) and "away" (when aphids were transplanted onto a foreign tree population). I then counted the number of offspring each aphid produced (this was the dependent variable).  Right now, I am modeling offspring with a poisson distribution.

my model is: fullmodel <- glm(offspring ~ Aphid_Population + homeaway + Aphid_Population:homeaway, family = poisson).

When graphing the data and looking at means, it seems that there is a very strong pattern, For all 3 aphid populations, home aphids produced between 1.7 and 3.4 more offspring than away aphid. With that, I am expecting a significant homeaway effect.

if I use >anova(fullmodel)  homeaway is sig. (p <.00001)
If I use >summary(fullmodel) the p associated with homeaway is .0009

BUT, if I create a reduced model (model_nohomeaway <- glm(offspring ~ Aphid_Population + Aphid_Population:homeaway, family = poisson)
the deviance = 0 (and it report the p-value as 0) ??????? It's these last results that don't make sense to me.

Am I doing something wrong?
Which one (if any) of these methods is giving the most robust and believable results?

Comment: What exactly doesn't make sense for you?

Comment: Hi Tim,  I'm confused about 2 things.  First, the inconsistent results.  Why are multiple models indicating a significance of the variable homeaway, but the anova that compares the full model to one without homeway is not significant (doesn't this technique test for the sig. of homeaway?).  Also, it's confusing to graph the data and see what appears to be a strong pattern, but I'm confused as to why the anova(fullmodel, model_no_homeaway) doesn't provide a significant p-value.  I'm still unsure/confused about which of these methods (if any) is a robust way to analyze the data.